# Is it possible to just display image in JSF dataTable which is stored in local system?

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a dataTable as below. And need to display an Image that is stored in localsystem based on Status(Success/Failure) in another column next to Status. I tried using

```
<h:graphicImage value="../../images/failure.png" alt="Failure">
```

But it's not displaying image.Is it possible to add images like that?

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{state.Status}" var="dataItem" id="Tbl1" >      
        <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Status" />
        </f:facet>
        <rich:column>
           <f:facet name="header">State</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{dataItem.State}"/>
        </rich:column>  
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Status</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{dataItem.Status}"/>
        </rich:column>  

        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Image</f:facet>
                ImageDisplay 
        </rich:column>  
    </rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: What is the 'local system' ? The client side? Then try if you can succeed in plain html that is served from a server. Most likely (100%) not. So you cannot do that in JSF either since JSF is in this regard just an html generator. If it is is an image from the file system on the web server then there are about 25 'duplicate' questions in Stackoverflow and lots to be found via a searchengine (and this question is also not datatable related)

Comment: JSF is system where page content is prepared on server. It means if you need to display image then server should know where image is stored. Because local system is not always accessible from server, it is better to store images on server or in DB. For displaying image(s) on page you can 1) add image(s) in your application (for example in web/images folder); 2) display image(s) using relative path (which is path on server not in local system).

Comment: Thank you.. I have added in server itself..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<h:graphicImage value="../../images/failure.png" alt="Failure">
```

Replacing attribute value by url solved the problem.Now image gets displayed.

```
<h:graphicImage url="../../images/failure.png" alt="Failure">
```

Comment: This is **NOT** in the local filesystem (unless you Run on 127.0.0.1 AND use IE).